# update_post_meta on multi-dimensional array options

Tags: php

When updating the database, I use `update_post_meta($employee->ID, '_email_address', $record->email);` and update this result:

```php
object(stdClass)[1295]
  public 'email' => string 'he@fhflondon.co.uk' (length=32)
```

How does one target an inner array for files such as leadership, profile?

```php
object(stdClass)[1295]
 public 'biography' => string '' (length=0)
 public 'files' => 
    object(stdClass)[1294]
      public 'leadership' => null
      public 'profile' => null
      public 'blog' => null
      public 'thumbnail' => null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, `get_post_meta` and its associated APIs all work on key/value pairs, you can update the value, but you can't update a sub-section of it. **You have to retrieve the entire value, modify it, then put it back as a whole.**

Additionally, values are always strings, so to make this work WordPress will PHP serialize your data, introducing a raft of security attack vectors ( object deserialisation attacks for example ). Your post meta value is also very difficult to search for.

Instead, avoid this and all the problems associated by using multiple key/value pairs instead of serialising data into a single key/value pair. Remember, you can have several post meta key/values with the same key, keys aren't unique!

And if you must store multidimensional data in a serialised format, use JSON instead. Don't rely on WP to flatten out your objects and arrays into strings